# How can i get specific parts inside "href"

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am new at html parsing and trying to get

```
document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.beyazperde.com/filmler/tum-filmleri/kullanici-puani/tur-13015/"+"?page=" + i).get();
Elements links = document.select("div.content a.no_underline");
for (Element link : links) 
{
    Element url = link.after("filmler/film-");
    System.out.println(url);
}
```

When I run i get these

```
<a class="no_underline" title="" href="/filmler/film-10080/"> Cesury&uuml;rek </a>
<a class="no_underline" title="" href="/filmler/film-9393/"> Schindler’in Listesi </a>
<a class="no_underline" title="" href="/filmler/film-28359/"> Piyanist </a>
```

But I want `"10080","9393","28359"` just these number not whole `<a>` tag.Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the href attribute and use it.

```
for (Element link : links) 
{
    String url = link.attr("href");
    String result = url.split("-")[1].replace("/","");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you convert that `url` to a string you can do it with a regular expression like:

```
url.replaceAll(".*href=\"/filmler/film-([0-9]*)/.*","$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.beyazperde.com/filmler/tum-filmleri/kullanici-        puani/tur-13015/"+"?page=" + i).get();
Elements links = document.select("div.content a.no_underline");
for (Element link : links) 
{
  Attributes attributes = link.attributes();
   String hrefVal = attributes.get("href");
   //use substring or any other logic to get your value
  // Element url = link.after("filmler/film-");
  System.out.println(hrefVal);
}
```

Comment: Do a little edit on your answer. It seems a typo error: `hrfe` to `href` :)

Comment: thanks pravin.But, I could not get what I want with url.replaceAll(".*href=\"/filmler/film-([0-9]*)/.*","$1"); Jorge,actually i didnt understand what there codes is doing.it gives me same output.

Comment: you will get `/filmler/film-10080/"` `/filmler/film-9393/` and `/filmler/film-28359/` as output and you can use some **substring logic** to get what you want